# how to set the values of the forms and make it stick even after refresh?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a long form, wherein, when I click the submit button the external js validation fires up and checks the validity of the input fields. If all the input fields passed the validation a jquery modal pops out asking the user to register or login.

Now, if the user choses to register and finishes registering from the modal, the modal closes and the page refreshes automatically and shows the user is automatically logged-in.

My problem now is that the input data from the long form he filled in before the registration got erased when the page refreshed.

**How can I make input fields not erase on refresh of a page? Is it possible to set the session within the external js file ? If yes, how can I to that?**

For example:

```
$_SESSION['resumetitle'] = $_POST['resumetitle'];
$_SESSION['resumeintro'] = $_POST['resumeintro'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['dob'] = $_POST['dob'];
$_SESSION['contacttel1'] = $_POST['contacttel1'];
$_SESSION['contacttel1type'] = $_POST['contacttel1type'];
$_SESSION['contacttel2'] = $_POST['contacttel2'];
$_SESSION['contacttel2type'] = $_POST['contacttel2type'];
$_SESSION['contacttel3'] = $_POST['contacttel3'];
$_SESSION['contacttel3type'] = $_POST['contacttel3type'];
$_SESSION['primaryemail'] = $_POST['primaryemail'];
$_SESSION['secondaryemail'] = $_POST['secondaryemail'];
$_SESSION['skype'] = $_POST['skype'];
$_SESSION['facebook'] = $_POST['facebook'];
$_SESSION['linkedin'] = $_POST['linkedin'];
$_SESSOIN['twitter'] = $_POST['twitter'];
$_SESSION['messenger'] = $_POST['messenger'];
$_SESSION['yahoo'] = $_POST['yahoo'];
$_SESSION['aol'] = $_POST['aol'];
$_SESSION['summaryofpositionsought'] = $_POST['summaryofpositionsought'];
$_SESSION['summaryofskills'] = $_POST['summaryofskills'];
$_SESSION['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];
```

Comment: Protip: instead of all those lines just do `$_SESSION = $_POST;`

Comment: the problem is how to set ?, because after the ajax registration via the modal, it refreshes the parent page , and all datas are gone, except from the fact that the registered user is now automatically logged-in

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is sending an XMLHTTPRequest to one of your pages along with session variable names and values, and that would set it. There may be better ways to do this.

Comment: let's say am gonna use $.ajax() of jquery, and then on the js file, it sounds like it would end up like this e.g  var aol = $('#aol').val() and aol will be included in the data param of $.ajax(), but am talking about "After" once the submit button is clicked even before the user registered on the popup...how to set the session now?

Answer (score 0):

Simply reassign your Post vars to the form elements. in elements value add

```
<?php $_POST['resumetitle'];?>
```

this should work fine.

Comment: U need to echo it . this may be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930396/can-you-set-a-form-field-value-with-php

Comment: This make sense , i'm sorry , i didn't understand your question clearly. In fact when you post the modal form for the login purpose , you submit only the form in the modal, and that's why you are unable to view your long form values and as a result unable to echo them. I don't think this is the best way to do things , but u have to , when validating your data try to add a hidden field containing your form values in the modal , then this hidden field can  be accsible when you refresh the page.